# How do I remove Bootstrap Affix from an element under certain conditions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have an element where I'm using the [Twitter Bootstrap Affix](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#affix) plugin.  If the window gets vertically resized to the point where it is smaller than the height of the item, I'd like to remove the affix functionality from the element since you wouldn't be able to see all of it in the window.

So far I've tried this in the console just to see if it can be removed, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
$("#myElement")
  .removeClass("affix affix-top affix-bottom")
  .removeData("affix");

$(window)
  .off("scroll.affix.data-api, click.affix.data-api");
```

Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way?  How Can I programmatically remove the affix from an element that already had it applied?

Comment: I ended up here, because I could not get my sticky navigation to work properly. Eventually I ditched affix and went with this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_sticky.asp
Simple function, complete control. Needed some tuning, with document ready and resize, but working perfectly now.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I ended up going for a mostly CSS solution, similar to what @Marcin Skórzewski suggested.

This just adds a new class when the height of the window is shorter than the height of the element.

```
var sizeTimer;
$(window).on("resize", function() {
    clearTimeout(sizeTimer);
    sizeTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        var isWindowTallEnough = $overviewContainer.height() + 20 < $(window).height();

        if (isWindowTallEnough) {
            $overviewContainer.removeClass("affix-force-top");
        } else {
            $overviewContainer.addClass("affix-force-top");
        }

    }, 300);
});
```

And then in CSS, this class just gets added:

```
.affix-force-top{
    position:absolute !important;
    top:auto !important;
    bottom:auto !important;
}
```

---

**EDIT**

For bootstrap 3, this seems to be effective:

```
$(window).off('.affix');
$("#my-element")
    .removeClass("affix affix-top affix-bottom")
    .removeData("bs.affix");
```

Comment: Thanks for your Bootstrap 3 edit, this worked perfectly for me

Comment: Thanks for this. FYI--I don't need to remove the classes if I run `$(window).off('.affix');` before the element starts affix-ing, if that makes any sense.

Comment: @thekingoftruth Yes, true, but it doesn't hurt to attempt to remove the classes anyway, this way it will always work the same way no matter when i gets run.

Comment: Be careful if you have several affixed elements on your page and you want to disable only one! In this case, do not call `$(window).off('.affix');` or else all your affixed elements will be disabled :)

Answer (score 9):

**Deprecated: Answer refers to Twitter Bootstrap v2. Current version is v4.**

There are few options to try.

1. Use function for `data-offset-top`. Normally, you use the integer value, for number of scrolled pixels to fix the element. According to [documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#affix) you can use the JS function, that will calculate the offset dynamically. In this case you can make your function to return different number depending on the conditions of your choice.
2. Use [media query](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) to override affix CSS rule for small window (eg. height 200px or less).

I think, the second variant should be suitable for you. Something like:

```
@media (max-height: 200px) {
  .affix {
    position: static;
  }
}
```

If you would provide jsfiddle for your problem others could try to actually solve it, instead of giving just theoretical suggestion, that may or may not work.

PS. Bootstrap's navbar component uses media query for max-width to disable fixed style for small devices. It is good to do that not just because the screen size is to small for navbar, but in mobile devices `position: fixed;` CSS works really ugly. Take w look at `navbar` inside the `bootstrap-responsive.css` file.

Comment: I like the idea, but the media query would be a hard set number and would not be able to determine if the height of the element is smaller than the window height.  Also the function for the `top` property *could* work, but it would still return a number to begin affixing at. I need it to all-together NOT affix any longer.

Comment: You still should be able to use the offset function by returning very big number when you do not want to fix your menu. Bootstrap's components are meant to be easy start, not complete solution. If you need something more fancy, then own implementation of fixing an element position is an easy task if you are bit familiar with JS/jQuery. So, instead of patching affix it may be better to fix/unfix on your own with `on("scroll", ...)`.

Comment: I think is a good idea add a "!important" at the right of position: static. This way you will override the existing class setting.

Comment: @BernieSF It is better to avoid dirty hacks like `!important` if they are not really necessary IMHO. CSS selector specificity is the same as in Bootstrap2 file, so it is not necessary.

Answer (score 7):

Your `$(window).off` is close, according to @fat (author of bootstrap-affix.js) you can disable the plugin like this:

```
$(window).off('.affix');
```

That will disable the affix plugin.

See: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/5870

Comment: This disables all affixed blocks, however.

Answer (score 3):

On line 1890 of bootstrap is a conditional for whether the default action should be prevented. This allows your to listen for events and if some condition is met, prevent the affix from happening.

line 1890 from bootstrap:
if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) return

Example:

```
$('someselector')
.affix()
.on(
    'affix.bs.affix affix-top.bs.affix affix-bottom.bs.affix'
    , function(evt){  
        if(/* some condition */){  
            evt.preventDefault();  
        }  
    }
);
```

Comment: This answer contains information that should be in the Bootstrap docs. I was looking for a way to toggle affix and this is it.  Other solutions either eliminate affix for all elements or are unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this was answered, I just wanted to give my solution for this in case someone ran into a similar situation as mine.

I modified the offset top option to a ridiculous number that would never get scrolled to. This made it so I did not have to do $(window).off('.affix'); and disable affix for everything.

```
$('#element-id').data('bs.affix').options.offset.top = 1000000000;
```